# Create a exit function

Tags: c, malloc

I have school projects and we are using malloc and free a lot.

These are the authorized functions we can use : malloc, free, read and getline.

I would like to verify all calls to malloc in the program but it is kind of annoying to do, I don't know how to do it properly.

I was creating a function xmalloc that use exit when malloc returns NULL but as we can't use the exit function anymore that doesn't work.

```
void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *data = malloc(size);
    if (!data)
        exit(84);
    else
        return data;
}
```

How can I verify properly the functions in my program ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: What is your program supposed to do, if it has no output functions?

Comment: Can't use `exit()` ??? This is a terrible school project.

Comment: Is it a requirement for you to create an `exit` function, or is that just something you want to do?

Comment: @Beta We are also authorized to use the write function

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I would like to recreate an exit function, but we can't use kill for sending signal to PID. I don't know if it's possible

Comment: Dereferncing NULL will normally kill your program :-)

Comment: maybe use abort() instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities at hand. One is good, one is very, very bad.

The good possibility is that perhaps your instructor wants you to explore how to percolate error cases back to the original caller, perhaps through multiple levels of function calls. This is useful, and nothing magic: just requires checking the errors, and being careful with the little details.

The bad possibility is that your instructor is an idiot, who doesn't think it is important to check the return values from functions like `malloc()`, *"because they do not normally fail"*. This is a surprisingly common attitude nowadays, and leads to programs crashing without any warning (just a Segmentation Fault type of error) when e.g. memory or CPU time limits (*process limits*) are in use. Which is simply idiotic.

In the latter case, your error-and-abort-if-`malloc()`-fails helper function is the better option: at least the user can examine the exit status (in Bash, `echo $?`) to find some clue as to why the program pooped itself, and not left wondering what just happened.

In the hopes that this is surprisingly the former case — an exercise in how to pass error cases properly to the caller —, I shall continue.

---

First, a short backgrounder as to why this is actually useful to know.

Let's say you have a library, for example one that does colorspace conversions. (JPEG images and most movie formats use YUV or a similar colorspace, whereas most computer displays use RGB. New rendering software may support HDR, high dynamic range, where more bits are used to represent each color component than normally. So, this is a common need.)

If the total number of representable colors is small with respect to the size of the available memory, then the library might just precalculate the conversion from all possible colors from a source colorspace to the target colorspace. For example, for 16-bit RGB/YUV, this only takes 131072 bytes or 128 kiB of memory; for 24-bit, 50331648 bytes or 48 MiB.

Rather than try to find out, the program/library might have a global setting (between speed and frugal memory use, say five steps), and if sufficiently high, *try* the `malloc()`; otherwise fall back to slower, cached or even no-lookup-table functionality.

So, there are cases where memory allocation failure is not terminal.

I've dabbled with a C matrix library, where the matrix data is reference-counted and managed automatically; different matrices can even be realtime views of other matrices' contents. All the user/programmer needs to do, is to remember to "drop" the matrix after they no longer need it, and the memory is managed by the library.

In that library, one can postpone memory discards until explicitly asked, a large enough allocation occurs, or an allocation fails (in which case the currently unused data is freed, and the allocation retried). This is in order to let the user/programmer maximize speed when there is lots of memory available, but also sprinkle "cleanup notes" whenever the code is doing something like lots of disk I/O, where spending some CPU cycles in housekeeping is basically free.

In short, it is very useful to have a grip on how to handle errors, and how to propagate errors back to callers. In particular, it is sometimes important to be able to indicate the type or reason for the error, so the caller can make an informed decision as to how to proceed.

---

There are some basic truths we need to know, before we start:

- Because there is usually just one way to succeed, but many ways to fail, it is useful to use `0` for success, and nonzero for failure codes.

  Often, the function return value can be used to report the failure code (or zero if success). In this case, the test `(func(..))` is true if the call failed; the test `(!func(...))` is true if the call succeeded.

  You can also use `errno` from `<errno.h>` to hold the error code, if you use the `E...` constants your platform declares. You can then use `strerror(code)` from `<string.h>` to get a string describing the error, too.
- `free(NULL)` is safe, and does nothing.

  This means that if we initialize the pointers that will be used for dynamically allocated data to `NULL`, in error paths we can just `free()` them all. If they weren't allocated at all yet, no harm done, because `free(NULL)` is safe and harmless.
- `malloc(size)` and `realloc(NULL, size)` are exactly equivalent.

  I rarely use `malloc()` at all, but `realloc()` often. Combined with the above, when I know I need at least `size` chars dynamically allocated in some array, I can just call `realloc()` to resize it, regardless of whether some memory was already dynamically allocated there or not.

  This is also compatible with POSIX.1 functions like `getline()`. There is no need to `malloc()` an initial line buffer; just initialize the buffer to `NULL` and allocated size to `0`, and the first `getline()` call will dynamically allocate a new buffer if necessary.
- `realloc(oldptr, newsize)` returns one of three things.

  If it returns `NULL`, the contents at `oldptr` are still unchanged; `oldptr` is *not* freed.

  Often, the call returns `oldptr` when successful.

  The call may instead return a completely new pointer, different from `oldptr`. In that case, all the data (from `oldptr` up to the size of the old allocation) is automagically copied to the region pointed to by the returned pointer.

  The practical effect of this is that you do not want to `realloc()` linked list or tree nodes, or any other data structures, when pointers to the old location of the structure may exist. This is a "gotcha" that may sometimes bite new programmers, because they are unaware that `realloc()` may (but usually does not) move the memory region.
- When cleaning up, the order of the `free()` calls does not need to be the same as their allocation order.

  I personally like to do it in the opposite order, but the reason is that it helps me perceive the symmetry: to me, it's like keeping braces `{` and `}` balanced... It might help you too, or it may not be worth the effort.

  (It may actually help a bit with most typical C library allocators, but it is all hand-waving, and not worth worrying about at all. It might be an interesting thing to experiment with, when you progress to the point where you get interested in memory fragmentation and cache effects; but even then, each C library and even library version may behave differently.)

Let's consider a case where a function requires two temporary dynamically allocated arrays, of size `SIZE1` and `SIZE2`, and an internal helper function it calls uses an additional dynamic array, of size `SIZE3`:

```
static int helper(/* arguments omitted */)
{
    char *temp;

    temp = malloc(SIZE3);
    if (!temp)
        return ENOMEM;

    /* Do stuff */

    free(temp);
    return 0;
}

int some_work(/* parameters omitted */)
{
    int *data1 = NULL;
    double *data2 = NULL;
    int result;

    data1 = malloc(SIZE1 * sizeof data1[0]);
    data2 = malloc(SIZE2 * sizeof data2[0]);
    if (!data1 || !data2) {
        free(data2);
        free(data1);
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    /* Do some work */

    /* We might even discard one of them
       here, if we know it won't be needed
       anymore. To keep the cleanup simple,
       we just NULLify the variable if we free() it.
    */
    if (somecondition) {
        free(data1);
        data1 = NULL;
    }

    /* Do some further work */

    result = helper();
    if (result) {
        free(data1);
        free(data2);
        return result;
    }

    /* Do some more work */

    /* Done. Success. */
    free(data1);
    free(data2);
    return 0;
}
```

I use a return value of `0` to indicate success, and nonzero values (currently only `ENOMEM`) to indicate failure or error.

The `static` function qualifier (used for the internal helper function) means it is only visible in this compilation unit (source file), and will not be accessible from outside. It is useful especially in libraries, if you do not want internal library functions to be callable from outside.

Because the helper function does an unconditional assignment to `temp` at the start of the function, there is no need to initialize it to `NULL`.

(If you find any part of this unclear, do let me know in a comment, and I shall attempt to find a better wording, or construct a better example.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply which helped me on how to handle errors through several levels of calling functions.

That's exactly what they ask us, to be able to handle errors through several calls to functions. We are evaluated by automated tests, some tests voluntarily fail malloc to see if we have succeeded in error management (our program must absolutely not crash). There must also be no memory leakage even in case of error (malloc fails, input error or any other).

Thanks again for your help!